# How to load an agent by specifying a class instead of a jar

Tags: java, instrumentation, jvm-hotspot

When using the Virtual Machine class using the `loadAgent` method

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html

is it possible to specify a class as opposed to a jar

Comment: As you can see for yourself, there is no such method. But what’s stopping you from putting the class into a jar file?

Comment: @Holger. I think that's probably the best option.